# Hosting HTML/CSS/JS on Samsung Smart TV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I want to develop a simple remote control web application that I can access from my smartphone/tablet/laptop to change channel/volume/source of my Samsung Smart TV.

Is is possible to host a simple webapp (HTML/CSS/JS) on a Samsung Smart TV that other devices on the same subnet can consume? For instance by accessing:

```
http://samsung-smart-tv-ip-address/remote.
```

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Thomas

Comment: Theoretically if you have write permissions on the tv and this directory is visible why not. The real question is. You have those permissions?

Answer (score 0):

For Smartphones you already have remote control app delivered from Samsung and it is quite good.

Just search your Play Store.